# Can someone fully explain link summoning?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Can someone explain the new rules that Konami is planning for yugioh on link summoning and how it relates to the rest of the game? Also, when are they planning to make the rules an official mechanic to the game?

Comment: Nobody can officially determine the release date for Link Monsters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link summoning is something new to *Yu-gi-oh*.  It involves Special Summoning Link monsters from your Extra Deck. Basically, you take some 'Link Materials ', and send them to the Graveyard. These monsters affect other zones on the field, and these at called Linked Zones. They are useful for other effects.

Answer (score 4):

Let's see...

#### Short answer

Link Summoning is the act of using monsters you control as Link Materials, to summon a Link Monster from your Extra Deck.  It's basically Contact Fusion mk.2.

---

#### Long answer

Link Summoning is the act of using monsters on your side of the field as Link Materials, for the Link Summon of a Link Monster in your Extra Deck; these Link Materials are sent to the Graveyard, just like tributes, Fusion Materials, and Synchro Materials.

The number of Link Materials that must be used is equal to the summoned monster's Link Number (i.e., a Link 2 monster needs 2 materials, and a Link 4 monster needs 4 materials); if a Link Monster is used as a Link Material, you can use it as a number of monsters equal to its Link Number, but this isn't required (i.e., a Link N monster can count as either 1 material or N materials for a Link Summon).  Link Monsters can also specify a number of required materials (e.g., [Decode Talker](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Decode_Talker) requires 2+ monsters), along with other qualities such as types or attributes (e.g., "Decode Talker" requires Effect monsters), all of which must be met (e.g., since "Decode Talker" requires 2+ Effect Monsters, it cannot be summoned using another Link 3 monster as the sole material, even though that would satisfy the Link Number requirement).

This Link Monster, due to residing in the Extra Deck, must be summoned to an Extra Monster Zone (the two in the middle of the field, between both players' sides).  If there are already one or more Link Monster(s) on the field, and one or more of their Link Markers point to one of your Main Monster Zones (the original five, on your side of the field), then that pointed-to zone(s) is a Link Point(s), and can be treated as an Extra Monster Zone when summoning from the Extra Deck.

---

To my knowledge, those are the only rules specifically regarding Link Summoning.  Related rules would be the rules regarding Link Monsters themselves (such as that they're unaffected by effects that change Battle Position, or anything regarding Link Markers), and rules regarding Extra Monster Zones and Main Monster Zones (as mentioned in the final paragraph, above).